# How can I turn a integral and a fractional part back into a f32?

Tags: rust, floating-point

So I have a number, say `4.2`, I can extract the integral and fractional parts like so:

```rust
let value = 4.3;
let integral = f32::trunc(value);
let fractional = get_frac(value); // returns '3'
```

This returns the correct things, but how can I turn this back into a `f32`? I'm storing these as integers and then only at a later date need to convert them back into a float.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32177c3511ef558f1c98ef78cbd2f680) is how I'm doing the conversion

Comment: Use the `+` operator? Just guessing.

Comment: Wait a second, I forgot to add that I'm storing these as integers somewhere else. So I'd be adding `4` and `3`, which does not equal `4.3`

Comment: `fract` returns `0.3`, not `3`.

Comment: Damn, I'm normally better at remembering these details. I edited the question to include a link to the Playground showing off how I'm doing it

Comment: `let res: f32 = format!("{}.{}", integral, fraction).parse().unwrap();`? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0af4f36df4e09b76a377de531087ed6

Comment: [`integral as f32 + fraction as f32 * 0.1`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8eab660cf515a4e1e7f10f13ce04df39)?

Comment: You also need to store a piece of magic to help you distinguish between 4.2, 4.02 and 4.002.

Comment: It might help to expand just slightly on why you are splitting this for storage in the first place.

Comment: @GManNickG I'm caching meshes I generated in a hash map, where the key is the color value of the mesh, and for that I needed a Color type that implemented `Eq` and `Hash`. To do this I created a type `ColorComponent` with a field `fractional: u32`, `integral: u32` and `commas: u8` which can derive `Eq`, PartialEq` and `Hash`. In my `get_frac` function I'm rounding to the nearest 8th comma place, which I picked because it's accurate enough while excluding rounding errors

Comment: You would probably have enough precision if you stored each color component as fixed-point `u32` with e.g. `let fixed_red = (red * 65536) as u32;` and back with `let red = fixed_red as f32 / 65536;` (in fact, unless you're doing scientific processing on those colors, you can probably get away with storing them as `u16`).

Comment: @Jmb yeah I thought of that as well, and tried it, but for some reason it didn't work and all of my meshes were being rendered as white. May be because I just implemented it wrong

Answer (score 7):

Your function `get_frac()` inherently can't be inverted, since it maps different fractional parts to the same integer value. For both `4.2` and `4.02`, the return value of `get_frac()` is 2. There is no way to tell from just the result which original value you started with.

A better approach would be to decide how many digits you want to include in your integer representation of your floating point number. If you want to include, say, four decimal digits, simply multiply your number by 10,000 and round to an integer. This operation can be approximately inverted by dividing by 10,000 again.

Comment: I decided to store the amount of places after the comma as well and then do `integral + fractional / (commas * 10) `, so in this case that'd be `4 + 2 / (1 * 10)` which is just `4 + 0.2`, which returns the correct number

Comment: @MindSwipe I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, but I have doubts that this approach is useful. I also doubt that `commans * 10` is what you want there.

Comment: @MindSwipe Shouldn't that be `integral + fractional / 10.pow(commas)`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the *best* way, but working, would be to transform to string, then parse it:

```rust
let res: f32 = format!("{}.{}", integral, fraction).parse().unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e18ed03fe7668e3ba1a621f6f22d9c24)